# Перенос строки на пробеле

Tags: javascript, html, css

делаю калькулятор на языке javascript, перед этим сверстав его, и возник вопрос, если я ввожу очень длинное число, то оно переносится, как только строчка заканчивается, как бы его переносить только на пробеле? [image: Пример введенного числа]

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00AAFF, #00FF6C);
}

.calculator-grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}

.calculator-grid>button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

.calculator-grid>button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

.output {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.output .previous-operand {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.output .current-operand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
      <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
      <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-all-clear>AC</button>
    <button data-clear>C</button>
    <button data-operation>pow</button>
    <button data-operation>÷</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operation>*</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operation>+</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operation>-</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-operation>sqrt</button>
    <button data-equals>=</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

previous operand и current operand - окна вывода этих чисел
передача в них текста осуществляется следующим образом:

```
integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('ru', {maximumFractionDigits: 0})
```

Далее:

```
 this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = integerDisplay;
```

при использовании `white-space: pre-wrap`
текст не переносится вообще при innerText, если текст вводить в саму разметку, все работает.
[image: при white-space]

Comment: @UModeL добавил

Comment: если время терпит, то вечером займусь вашим вопросом плотнее - там подводных камней навалом, на самом деле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у Вас автоматом добавляются пробелы для разрядов, то решение простое - `white-space: pre-wrap`:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00AAFF, #00FF6C);
}

.calculator-grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}

.calculator-grid>button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

.calculator-grid>button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

.output {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  /*word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;*/
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.output .previous-operand {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.output .current-operand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
      <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand" contenteditable>555 555 555 555 555 555 555 555 555</div>
      <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"contenteditable>555 555 555 555 555 555 555 555 555</div>
    </div>
    <button data-all-clear>AC</button>
    <button data-clear>C</button>
    <button data-operation>pow</button>
    <button data-operation>÷</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operation>*</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operation>+</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operation>-</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-operation>sqrt</button>
    <button data-equals>=</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Добавил `input` для теста вставки с помощью JS через `innerText`:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00AAFF, #00FF6C);
}

.calculator-grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}

.calculator-grid>button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

.calculator-grid>button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

.output {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  /*word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;*/
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.output .previous-operand {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.output .current-operand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input class="test" oninput="document.querySelector('.current-operand').innerText = this.value;">
  <div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
      <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand">555 555 555 555 555 555 555 555 555</div>
      <div data-current-operand class="current-operand">555 555 555 555 555 555 555 555 555</div>
    </div>
    <button data-all-clear>AC</button>
    <button data-clear>C</button>
    <button data-operation>pow</button>
    <button data-operation>÷</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operation>*</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operation>+</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operation>-</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-operation>sqrt</button>
    <button data-equals>=</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: К сожалению, почему то с innerText не работает, хотя передаю в него уже строку с пробелами. И если использовать только white-spacing, то число перестает вообще переноситься

Comment: @SomVolodya: Вы `contenteditable` из моего кода убрали? Оно только для тестов. Здесь же работает, так?

Comment: да, убрал, но это не работает с js-ом, почему то, хотя с word-break текст переносится, только не так, как мне нужно

Comment: @SomVolodya: что-то Вы не так вставляете. Дополнил ответ - тестируйте.

Comment: @SomVolodya: скрипт или регулярка, которые разбивают число, должны разбивать простым `&#32;`, но не `&nbsp;` ! Проверьте.